# Unable to locate tasksel or lamp-server

Tags: 14.04, lamp, tasksel

I'm trying to install lamp server on ubuntu desktop 14.04

I start with `sudo apt-get update`. This process does not seem to complete though. After the Get: 1 list completes I have

```
Get:2 http://www.plexapp.com lucid
InRelease                                   
69% [2 InRelease gpgv 23.3 kB] [1 Sources 2,792 kB/6,399 kB 44%]
[Waiting for hSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/www.plexapp.com_repo_dists_lucid_InReleasIgn http://    www.plexapp.com lucid InRelease                                     
E: GPG error: http://www.plexapp.com lucid InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

Do I need to fix this? If so how?

I then go on with: sudo apt-get install tasksel

But get

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/    linux.dropbox.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unable to locate package tasksel
```

As you might expect this following command though attempted does not work:

sudo tasksel install lamp-server

I have also tried

sudo apt-get install lamp-server^

Which yields the following

```
Note, selecting 'apache2-bin' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-readline' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-mpm-prefork' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libmysqlclient18' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-data' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-cli' for task 'lamp-server'
libmysqlclient18 is already the newest version.
libmysqlclient18 set to manually installed.
mysql-common is already the newest version.
mysql-common set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-bin : Depends: 
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 but it is not installable or 
libaprutil1-dbd-mysql but it is not installable or
libaprutil1-dbd-odbc but it is not installable or
libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql but it is not installable or
libaprutil1-dbd-freetds but it is not installable
Depends: libaprutil1-ldap but it is not installable
mysql-client-5.5 : Depends: libdbd-mysql-perl (>= 1.2202) but it
is not installable
    Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not installable
    Depends: libterm-readkey-perl but it is not installable
    mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not
    installable
    Recommends: libhtml-template-perl but it is not installable
    mysql-server-core-5.5 : Depends: libaio1 (>= 0.3.93) but it
    is not installable
    php5-common : Depends: php5-json but it is not installable
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```